# android studio tablayout icon

Tags: javascript, android

Hello guys im trying to do Tablayout in my project on android studio by following this https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout (doing it up to the "Add Icons to TabLayout") Recently, but somehow my icon wont appear, already added style but still nothing appear, anyone know why?
Thanks

*note : i also try to create new project and copy the code exactly but the result is the same

on activity :

```js
public class SlidingTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sliding_tabs);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        //set icon to tablayout
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.clock);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.clock);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
        });

    }


    private class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String viewfragment [] = {"slidingtab1","slidingtab2"};
        private Context Mycontext;

        public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, Context applicationContext) {
            super(supportFragmentManager);
            this.Mycontext = applicationContext;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new SlidingTab1_Activity();
                case 1:
                    return new SlidingTab2_Activity();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return viewfragment.length;
        }
    }
}
```

```js
On The xml :
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:background="#cdc36e"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Style

```js
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>
  </style>

        
  <style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Can you post your styles.xml, containing `MyCustomTabLayout`? You should be setting tabTextAppearance as `<item name="textAllCaps">false</item>`.

Comment: yea already did that, i guess the problem with the setup of "Design Support Library", but still dont know what i missed
 *added my style xml

Comment: solved it without using fragment getTitle just directly using
" tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.clock); "
at my activity

*update activity